# CSS Style extension with renaming

Tags: html, css, extend

My question is about renaming and extending of css styles. 
Lets say I imported a css file which has a style below

```
// These two styles are from imported css

buttonStyle{ ....    }    
buttonStyle:hover{....}


// I want to create a new style 
   myStyle extends buttonStyle:hover { ...}
```

Is it possible to extend my new style so that my style will be merged with `buttonStyle+buttonStyle:hover+  myStyle` content

Comment: Not in CSS but you can do this using [SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/).

Answer (score 0):

We cant extend properties in CSS, Why cant you do like this:

Here in the imported CSS we are just adding myStyle along with the other two

```
buttonStyle, myStyle {
 .... 
}

buttonStyle:hover, myStyle {
....
}

myStyle {
// Add on properties for myStyle
}
```

So that myStyle will get the properties of first two and then the third one and the duplicated properties will be overrided with respect to its priority.

Comment: Bease buttonStyle is an external css so that i cannot put my style next to it.